# How does one achieve a topology change?

Tags: general-topology

I was asking myself how one should formalize a topology change that modifies a topological space into another (reversibly or irreversibly), so that the topological invariants of the initial space are not preserved by the transformation. How are these transformations formalized in general? Does there exist a general framework by which one formalizes such transformations?

Comment: A discontinuous function is what you are looking for.

Comment: Continuous maps generally don't preserve any topological invariants. If the invariant in question is functorial, then a continuous map will induce a map on invariants but that is all. It might be a good idea to at least read a small portion of an introductory topology text before trying to ask questions using terms you cannot define.

Comment: What do you mean by "topology change"?

Comment: @PVAL Thank you for your kindest comment. I did, in fact.

Comment: @RobArthan I mean a transformation on a topological space, that doesn't preserve some selected topological invariants. If you want to know what I exactly had in mind and what my question was aimed to, I was thinking about the fact that a suitable Lie group can totally determine the metric of a Riemannian (or pseudo-Riemannian) manifold, so that modifying the group modifies the metric of the manifold on which it acts as a symmetry group. Nonetheless, a Lie group is first of all a topological group; thus if one wants to attain certain modifications of the metric, one should modify...

Comment: ... its topological invariants through a topology change of the group itself. The example I have in mind is the transformation of a space-like dimension into a time-like dimension (with reference to special relativity) when working with the Euclidean space, let's say, $\Bbb{R}^{2}$. One achieves this transformation by switching from the metric $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ to the metric $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ In terms of the symmetry (Lie) groups, you must go from $SO^{+}(2)$ to $SO^{+}(1,1)$.

Comment: The problem is that while the first one is a compact group, the second one is not. So a topology changing transformation is needed in order to formalize the space$\to$time transformation only talking about the symmetries of the manifold. I was wondering whether one could find some transformation that in a homotopy-like fashion produces a continuum of intermediate (let's call them) "geometric states" of the manifold, and at the same time achieve the desired topology change (i.e., in this case, at least compactness and the fundamental group, I guess).

Comment: This led me to ask how in general one deals with topology changing transformations.

Comment: hmmm a Riemannian metric is an additional structure on a topological space, by changing metric you should not be changing the topology. I think what you have in mind is possibly more on the line of: consider spaces obtained/determined by a transitive action of a Lie group (homogeneous spaces or something like that maybe). I think that in most cases they come with a natural preferred metric. What happens to the space and its metric if the group is smoothly deformed into another Lie group? Not sure though and in any case do not know enough to answer...

Comment: I meant something quite different. When you define a metric on a smooth manifold, that metric comes with a symmetry group, i.e. the group of the transformations of the manifold which leave the metric unchanged. Conversely, to groups of transformations of a manifold can correspond metrics that are invariant with respect to those transformations. These groups are often Lie groups, thus topological groups. Here the topology that you want to modify is that of the Lie group, not that of the manifold. By modifying the symmetry group (and its topology), you can modify the metric of the manifold.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think a continuous map cannot change topological invariants? The quotient map that identifies two points on a circle to give a figure-eight is certainly continuous; it changes the fundamental group from $\mathbf Z$ to $F_2$, the free group on 2 generators.

Even more basically, every topological space has a unique map to a one-point space, which is (trivially) continuous.

**Edit:** this answered the original version of the question, which has been edited.

Comment: This is not so general, is it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I am giving counterexamples to your assertion "We know, of course, that such a transformation cannot be a continuous map between topological spaces." What is not general?

Comment: You specifically answered to that assertion, which, I admit, is totally incorrect, as I was really thinking about homeomorphisms and some properties that are preserved by homotopy equivalences. In my question, I was asking whether there is a general, accepted framework by which one formalizes topology changes. I was not looking for counterexamples, as you may have understood if you hadn't get stuck to that one assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous map generally do not preserve topological invariants - think of the constant map, which maps whatever topological space to a point and is always continuous.

By definition, a topological invariant is preserved by homeomorphisms: continuous bijective maps with continuous inverse.

Comment: Yes, I deleted that line, as it seems that it made the following questions unanswerable.

Comment: Well, I think the question is too vague to be answerable at the moment. Or answer would be useless, any non homeomorphism will change the topology somehow. If you are more specific about which changes and which spaces you are thinking about there may be more useful answers. For example compactness and connectedness are preserved by continuous maps while fundamental groups generally aren't - but transform "nicely".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The question was intended to be general, but I understand that it may be too general. Can I deduce from your answer that there is no established framework in topology by which one deals with topology changes?

Comment: Well, as I said is more the fact that "topology change" is too broad a notion to admit a useful framework - basically it is equivalent to asking "what are the topological effects of a non-homeomorphism?". Well quite a lot can happen... I gave some concrete suggestions with reference to your Lie group example above, but I do not think I know enough to be more than hand waving (at best).

Comment: Gosh, I didn't notice that I was talking to the same person. I totally understood your point, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to know about bitopological spaces :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitopological_space

Comment: Notice these spaces can get married in around 31 states now ;).

Comment: For one moment I thought it was uncyclopedia :-) Not bad at all! At least now I can think of one way in which a topological space can be both compact and noncompact at the same time, while still being a topological space!

Comment: @Giorgio Comitini: Ha Ha, yes, it does sound like it is made up.